# Correctness of quick sort in C

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, quick-sort

What do you think of this piece of code ? This is an implementation of quick sort in C, but I'm not sure about the quality and correctness.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int tab[], int a, int b)
{
  int temp = tab[a];
  tab[a] = tab[b];
  tab[b] = temp;
}

void quickSort(int tab[], int begin, int end)
{
  int left = begin-1;
  int right = end+1;
  const int pivot = tab[begin];


  if(begin >= end)
    return;

  while(1)
    {
      do right--; while(tab[right] > pivot);
      do left++;  while(tab[left] < pivot);

      if(left < right)
        swap(tab, left, right);
      else break;
    }

  quickSort(tab, begin, right);
  quickSort(tab, right+1, end);
}


int main(void)
{
    int tab[5] = {5, 3, 4, 1, 2};
    int i;

    quickSort(tab, 0, 4);

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", tab[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Is it the standard way of implementing a quick sort in C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is not a bad implementation of Quicksort but it has a flaw, inherent to the Quicksort algorithm, that you can easily fix.  I tested the code with this main:

```
const int testsize = 100000;

int main(void)
{
    int tab[testsize];
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i < testsize; i++)
        tab[i] = i;

    tab[0] = testsize+1;
    quickSort(tab, 0, testsize-1);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this is deliberately the worst case scenario for Quicksort in which it takes \$O(n^2)\$ time to sort.  This code took 11.85 seconds on my machine.  Quicksort works best on randomly arranged data, so paradoxically, you can often actually *improve* sorting time by randomly shuffling the data before you start.  I wrote this rather simple-minded shuffle routine:

```
void shuffle(int tab[], int begin, int end)
{
    for (; begin < end/2; ++begin)
        swap(tab, begin, rand()%end);
}
```

When I inserted a call to `shuffle()` just before the call to `quickSort()` in `main`, the time to sort the same data dropped to 0.026 seconds.  By comparison, the standard `qsort()` sorts in 0.006 seconds on this same machine.

Also, more generally, I'd be inclined to pass two pointers to `swap` rather than an array and two indices.  The code may be very slightly faster, but it's certainly more general.

The code could also be made more general by using the same parameters as the `qsort()` routine in `<stdlib.h>` but then, that's already written. :)

Comment: Isn't rand()%end a bad practice (modulo bias..) ? I know it's irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @user3585425: yes, it is, but as you say, it really doesn't matter in this case.  Even if that were fixed, it's still a simple-minded shuffle.  :)

Comment: I don't think shuffling is a solution. The probability of getting the worst case _before_ shuffling is exactly equal to the probability to end up with the worst case _after_ it. A little better remedy is using more sophisticated pivot selection strategy (such as a median of 3 or 5 elements)

Comment: @vnp: in theory, your assertion about probabilities may be valid, but in practice it definitely is not.  In the real world, nearly ordered lists are actually quite common.  Also, rather than tinkering with modifications to Quicksort, one could simply use a heap sort.  Which is "better" depends mostly on the requirements of the problem at hand.

Comment: @Edward: 100% agree with our definition of better. Most politely disagree with all the rest.

Comment: @vnp: it probably has to do with our different experiences.  Quicksort is fine if you're interested in average time, but if you need a time guarantee, as with real-time systems, other algorithms perform better in that context.  See, for, example, [this paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/3706941_Which_sorting_algorithms_to_choose_for_hard_real-time_applications/file/9fcfd50ff15599c760.pdf) and [this one on soft real-time](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220414433_Real-Time_Performance_of_Sorting_Algorithms/file/9fcfd50ad3f528d9e7.pdf).

Comment: This is slightly unrelated, but is there a way to prove that my function actually sorts its input ?

Comment: @user3585425: Here's how I would prove it:  `for(i=1; i<testsize; ++i) assert(tab[i] >= tab[i-1]);`

Comment: As `qsort()` is mentioned here, wanted to add for clarity:  The standard function `qsort()` does not define the algorithm used to do sorting.  `qsort()` may used the "Quick Sort" algorithm, it may not.

Comment: @Edward You realize I'm asking if it's possible to prove that this function actually sorts its input for every possible input, not if one run of this function sorts one particular input.

Answer (score 3):

- I'd recommend to use pointers instead of indices. It is one less parameter to pass down the recursion.
- Algorithms on ranges are somewhat simpler if they are given semi-open ranges (that is, `begin` *is* the first element, and `end` is the first element beyond the range).
- No raw loops. Factor out the `while` loop into a function on its own. Now not only the code becomes cleaner, but you also get a very important `partition` algorithm for free. You may also want to make one step deeper, and recognize that `do... while` loops are also important algorithms (namely, `find_forward` and find_backward`).
- Once the `partition` is factored out, you may want to eliminate one of the recursions. The actual recursive call shall go into the smaller partition.
- Terminating a recursion early is a serious optimization, but it is beyond the scope of this review.